# API - Custom property as evaluated result

Tags: solidworksapi

Just a heads up but I’m not a programmer or API expert.

I am using property tab builder to write a series of properties into my files. I’m then using a macro that then concatenates them nicely into a file name on my drawing sheet.

Unfortunately, at the moment this includes the SolidWorks expression $PRP:"SW-File Name" rather than the evaluated result.

Is it possible to have a macro that reads in the file name and then writes this to a new property name? This may not be the most elegant method, but it would work with my macro.